# join for insert statement mysql syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

hey I have two tables and Im looking to make a mysql sytax statement for insert:

Table structure:

[image]

Im trying to insert userid and picturepath (which i can do) but how would I insert into flag in the user table aswell in the same insert syntax:

```
("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + fileuploadpaths + "')", cn);
```

theuserid is set by a session so I can reuse the string for that to know which coloum to insert into the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gonna have to do an update statment after the insert statement

```
 ("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + fileuploadpaths + "') "+
"GO UPDATE user SET flag = 1 WHERE UserID = "+theUserId+" GO", cn);
```

might work

try to execute this command in sql management if you have it with test data to make sure it allows this to work like this

Comment: are you sure? Not possible to do INSERT INTO p.Pictures LEFT JOIN u.User WHERE u.UserID = theuserid VALUES (bla, bla) ?? something like that?

Comment: you cant because its an INSERT statement but I was just thinking of somethign you could do since its just a nonquery statement

Comment: You can only insert into one table at a time in most databases.